# How can it be possible that I hear people's voices from my computer speaker?

Tags: rf, filter, noise, wireless, interference

I searched on the web and found it can apparently be due to truck drivers communicating on citizen's band radio which is around 20 MHz. Apparently this communication may cause interference with the frequencies used by computer's audio card.

How is it electronically and physically possible that these MHz communications are able to interfere with my laptop speaker? What is the explanation for this signal interference effect?

Is there something that will more likely to cause this interference? I mean, can this happen with every RF transmitted by anyone because they just need to be strong, or are there conditions (I don't know: transmitted carrier frequency signal, shape of signal, non-filtering in TX, etc.) that can increase the probability of creating interference?

Comment: Is the CB communication AM?

Comment: @winny I don't know. why is it important?

Comment: AM only requires a diode to demodulate. Making it very susceptible to not only audible interference but understandable interference. There must be a better English word for it. Eligible? Comprehensible?

Comment: @allexj Is it the speaker built into the laptop, or are you using external speakers with it? It's easier for the latter to pick up the signal with the long leads acting as aerials. How close are you to the trucks? If it was more common, we'd hear (no pun intended) more of it.

Comment: @winny intelligible?

Comment: Note that FM can be demodulated due to incidental phenomena -- multipath (reflections) and cable resonances can act as slope detection. And yes, CB is AM.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Bingo! That’s the one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your laptop is obviously sensitive to electromagnetic interference. It may be poorly designed, poorly shielded, or just faulty.

Strong RF signals may get picked up by PCB wiring or cabling inside the laptop, and as the audio chips obviously cannot handle RF, it may get demodulated into audio baseband in the internal chip semiconductor structures, and then it's just audio that is amplified to speakers.

So all the RF signal needs to do is to e.g. go into an op-amp with the intended laptop audio and then the opamp output audio comes out with the audio that got demodulated from the RF added.

Comment: is there something that will more likely to cause this interference? I mean, can this happen with every RF transmitted by anyone because they just need to be strong... or there are conditions (I don't know: transmitted carrier frequency signal, shape of signal, nonfilteringinTX, etc etc) that can increase probability to create interferences?

Comment: @allexj It depends on to what your device is sensitive to, maybe by accident, and then you have a RF source that it happens to be sensitive to. Try making a mobile phone call and bring the mobile phone near laptop, many audio devices will pick up the signal as periodic buzzing.

Answer (score 1):

Typically interference (RFI) is caused by strong radio signals and picked up by the wiring connected to your devices. For example speaker cables are a common culprit because the speaker port is often used as feedback to an earlier stage in the amplifier. Any wiring can cause problems, I remember years ago a transmitter getting into my keyboard cable and causing havoc. Some solutions are a suppressor on the cable (RF choke), shielding or bypass capacitors. It's a complex topic and there is lots of information available on the 'net.